# Point density and volume material woes in Blender Internal

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm currently working on an underwater mermaid scene, and I ran into several problems, first is that I can't usually get the halo particles to fade over time, which made me resort to putting the particle emitter inside a domain cube, giving the cube a volume material and using the Point Density texture to give the impression of opaque liquids dissolving under the sea.

This unfortunately resulted in disaster, as the entire domain cube is literally fogged up. I have the volume's base density set to 0, the Point Density texture tied to the right particle system and the texture is influencing the volume's density. The texture's blend mode is set to add.

If you have any solutions to my point density and volume material woes that don't involve switching to Cycles, let me know.

Comment: Why are you using the old Blender Internal renderer?

Comment: I'm making an original character as fandom for a cartoon that was produced somewhere in Italy, especially the one with the seven-membered team of fairies. In the renders featuring this character, photorealism is not the main goal, and I want these renders to be more stylized.

Comment: Which version are you using? What do you mean by Blender Internal?

Comment: Version 2.7, and Blender Internal is known as Blender Render on the rendering engine selection menu.